# Are corn kernels considered a grain

Tags: botany, nomenclature

I have seen corn described as a seed, a grain and a fruit. 
What are the kernels or a corncob considered to be? A grain, a seed or a fruit?

Comment: The fact that you asked about corn kernels is important, I think.  @March-Ho's answer is good, but the maize plant itself is a cereal grass.

Comment: I think the answer has to depend on the context.  To a farmer at harvest, it would be grain; at planting time, it would be seed.  And to a cook it might well be a vegetable most of the time, but a grain when making cornbread or tortillas.

Answer (score 2):

The grain of corn is known as a [caryopsis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caryopsis), which Merriam-Webster defines as:

> a small one-seeded dry [indehiscent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehiscence_%28botany%29) fruit (as of corn or wheat) in
>   which the fruit and seed fuse in a single grain

[image]

This image by Encyclopedia Britannica shows that the corn seed, enclosed by the seed coat (testa) is then further surrounded by the [pericarp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_anatomy#Pericarp_layers), which consists of the layers of tissue around the fruit.

Therefore, the corn kernel can be described as any of the terms that you have mentioned.

Comment: I like this line [here](http://ucanr.edu/sites/MarinMG/files/141899.pdf): "*Corn,* Zea mays, *belongs to the Poaceae family, and while eaten sometimes as a vegetable and sometimes as a grain,it is actually classified by botanists as a fruit, as are tomatoes, green peppers, cucumbers, zucchini and other squashes.*"